# c# webclient upload and download data from ssl

Tags: c#, ssl, webclient

I have a wamp server on windows. SSL configured correctly. In browser it is working threw https: . I have a script test.php and I want to download and upload some POST data to it. I have my c# code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
values.Add("paramtest", "testval");
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
byte[] result;   
result = client.UploadValues("https://127.0.0.1./test.php", "POST", values); 
string htmlCode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
textBox1.Text = htmlCode;
```

When runnign this code with http I got all the data. When put https, I got an error from the server:

> 400 Bad Request
>
> ## Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not
>   understand.

Have you got any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether this is the cause, but your url has a trailing '.' after the IP address:

try

```
result = client.UploadValues("https://127.0.0.1/test.php", "POST", values);
```

instead of

```
result = client.UploadValues("https://127.0.0.1./test.php", "POST", values);
```